# Mobx state with async call

Tags: mobx, mobx-react, mobx-state-tree

So I'm having mobx store:

```
...

 const Auth = types.model({
    token: types.optional(types.string, "")
 })

 export const AuthStoreModel = Auth
 .actions(self => ({
        login: flow(function* (email, password){
                const response = yield api.post('auth/login', {email, password});
                self.token = response.data.result.token;
        })
    })
 )

...
```

If I call that action store doesn't update and if I add try/catch it throws exception (not really helpful one). I tried moving around and using async/await (with .then()) instead flow with yield but nothing.

Moving self.token = ; above API call or removing API call, then it updates store.

Not sure where's the problem, I'm using React Native Ignite with their Bowser boilerplate.

If anyone could help, I'd be really grateful. Thanks

Comment: you should probably make sure it doesn't throw an exception?

Comment: @JoelHarkes Yeah but I have no idea why it throws anyway (error message is not helpful). Any yield I do is throwing exception...

Comment: Okay All I had to do is update self.token from another action.